# JQuery Plugin Website

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is there a website that lists all of the publicly available JQuery plugins?

Also, are these plugins usually open source or do some people charge you money to download them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of plug-ins is available at http://plugins.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery plugins are uncompilable since they are standard .js javascript files.  I've never seen any publicly available JQuery plugin that cost money.  I suppose its possible, but distribution would either be done on good faith in the customer, or to heavily obfuscate the source code.

Comment: Code doesn't need to be compiled or obfuscated to have a restrictive license

Answer (score 0):

Most jQuery plugins are open source with liberal licenses, like jQuery itself.